# AWS lightsail CLI command put-instance-public-ports doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, port, firewall, amazon-lightsail

So I'm trying to update firewall rules for my ligthsail instance. However, running the command

```
aws lightsail put-instance-public-ports --port-infos fromPort=22,protocol=TCP,toPort=22,cidrs=1.1.1.1 --instance-name Ubuntu-1
```

returns

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in portInfos[0]: "cidrs", must be one of: fromPort, toPort, protocol
```

In the description it seems that this functionality should be there? https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lightsail/put-instance-public-ports.html

Any idea where I mess up the command? Thanks!

Edit:

Updating aws cli version fixed the issue

Comment: The command is fine. Are you sure this is the exact command you use?

Comment: @Marcin yes, i copy pasted it from my console

Comment: @Marcin found the issue. Server had an outdated version of aws cli..... Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Glad it worked out. I will make an answer if you don't mind for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was not the command used. **The command was correct**. The problem was with the outdated AWS CLI used.

The solution was to **updated the AWS CLI**.